# Excel VBA code to fetch data from website

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I've developed the code below in order to get some information from a webpage (Internal IT support) into excel including: ticket ID, description, content, person assigned, first reply and all the information possible in order to report them according to our KPIs, now i don't know much about coding especially VBA, the code below fetch one piece of information in every run so i couldn't get a list of all the tickets and their information.

Please help me with a method or code to get this done.

Cheers :)

```
Private sub report_data_click ()
Dim IE as InternetExplorer
Dim HTML as variant
set IE = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.visible = false
ie.navigate "https://forum.fortinet.com"
while IE.busy
 do events
wend
while ie.readystate < 4
do events
wend
set HTML = ie.document 
set elements as variant 
set elements2 as variant
set elements3 as variant 
set elements4 as variant 
set elements = html.getelementsbyclassname ("contentlink")
for i=0 to elements.length - 1
sheet1.range ("A" & (9+1)) =elements(i).innertext
next i

set elements2 = html.getelementsbyclassname ("authorlink")
for i=0 to elements2.length - 1
sheet1.range ("A" & (9+1)) =elements2(i).innertext
next i

set elements3 = html.getelementsbyclassname ("performdateformat")
for i=0 to elements3.length - 1
sheet1.range ("A" & (9+1)) =elements3(i).innertext
next i

set elements4 = html.getelementsbyclassname ("Messagelink newpost")
for i=0 to elements4.length - 1
sheet1.range ("A" & (9+1)) =elements4(i).innertext
next i
IE.quit
set IE = Nothing 
End sub
```

Comment: Where on that page does it mention tickets and who tickets are assigned to etc? And can you show some sample data for expected outcome?

Comment: And the above does not compile. I can see lots of errors immediately. So, when you say "the code below fetch one piece of information in every run".... which code are you actually refering to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are from different language like vb.net because the way you have written the above script reminds me something of that sort. You just can't declare everything (specially Objects) as `variant` and `Set` them the way you have written. Try the below approach to get the data from every containter under class name `newActiveList-item`. I tried to create the script which should parse the three fields (mentioned in your script) from each container. If anything you wanna add, I think you can manage following the logic implemented below.

```
Private Sub ReportData()
    Const url As String = "https://forum.fortinet.com/"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, R&

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate url
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document
    End With

    For Each post In HTML.getElementsByClassName("newActiveList-item")
        With post.getElementsByClassName("authorlink")
            If .Length Then R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = .Item(0).getAttribute("href")
        End With
        With post.getElementsByClassName("performdateformat")
            If .Length Then Cells(R, 2) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
        With post.getElementsByClassName("messagelink")
            If .Length Then Cells(R, 3) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
    Next post
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library in order to execute the above script:

```
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: Thank you so much SIM, appreciated for your kind help and support and by the way I'm not familiar with any programming language unfortunately :(